# Undelete inode of deleted files

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, files

I accidentally deleted my documents folder in my home directory last sunday. I am desperately trying to recorver it with it content files.

After digging around, I came across a suggestion to use scalpel to help the recorvery, I have tried it, but because I dont have enough space on my hard disk, it fails carving.

I have decided today to use ｀debugfs｀,  and again have managed to screw up even more. What happened is - I executed;
       " 1. lsdel to view all deleted files inodes,"
       " 2. help to see all possible commands."

I saw ｀undel｀ which I immediately assumed meant undelete the inode to restore the files so I performed undel on all without jotting them down.

## Question

- Does this means I now can't recorver my files? If that is not the case;
- Is there a way to recorver the files without using the inodes, or perhaps  restore debufs inode history back to where it was previously?!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/09/recover-deleted-files-in-linux/ includes Scalpel and two additional applications to recover (undelete) files. Apps are Foremost and Photorec. Photorec has a ncurses-ish UI, so it may be easier to use it (I have not used it before).